Show $N = a^p-2^{-p} \cdot \left(\left(a+\sqrt{a^2-4a}\right)^p+\left(a-\sqrt{a^2-4a}\right)^p\right)+1$ is prime only if $p$ is prime?
For $a > 1$ and $a \neq 4$ , How to prove $$N = a^p-2^{-p} \cdot \left(\left(a+\sqrt{a^2-4a}\right)^p+\left(a-\sqrt{a^2-4a}\right)^p\right)+1$$ is prime only if $p$ is prime?
This is something I noticed while searching some properties of Gaussian-Mersenne and Eisenstein-Mersenne primes.
for example with $a = 5$, $N$ is prime for $p = 2, 7, 11, 17, 19, 23, 53, 67, 139, 173, 757, 1447, 1481, 1511, 1933, 2417$ and all are prime numbers.
I tried for others bases too and it seems than $p$ must be prime for $N$ is prime too.
And when $N$ is composite with $p$ prime, it seems the factor of $n$ are equals to $2kp+1$ like Mersenne numbers.
If this conjecture is true, is there a way to prove it ?

Your parentheses do not balance.  I have edited it the way I think you intended, but you should check.

Note $,N = (\alpha^{:!p}-1)({\bar \alpha}^{:!p}-1),$ for $,\alpha,\bar\alpha,$ roots of $,x^2-ax+a\ \ $

There are many counterexamples for $a=1$.

Thanks, I will edit for a > 1, this is a mistake

Write $\alpha=(a+\sqrt{a^2-4a})/2$. Note that $\alpha$ and $a/\alpha=(a-\sqrt{a^2-4a})/2$ are both roots of $x^2-ax+a$. Your conjecture may be stated as $$f(n)=(\alpha^n-1)((a/\alpha)^n-1)$$ is prime only if $n$ is prime. It suffices to prove that if $n$ is composite, then $f(n)$ is composite. If $k\mid n$, then $(x^k-1)\mid (x^n-1)$, so $$f(k)\mid f(n)$$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. The LHS and RHS are integers, so their ratio is a rational element of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. Since $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer, so are all elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. But the only algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}$ are the integers themselves, so the divisibility statement is also true in $\mathbb{Z}$. Furthermore, $|f(n)|$ is a strictly increasing function in $n$, so if $k$ is a proper divisor of $n$, then $f(k)$ is a proper divisor of $f(n)$. $\square$
The reason why this fails for $a=1$ is that $f(n)$ ends up actually being $3$-periodic with values $0,3,3,0,3,3,\ldots$, so we are not able to conclude that $f(k)\neq f(n)$ when $k$ is a proper divisor of $n$.

Yes, that's the idea in my (too terse?) hint $4$ days ago. $\ \ $

@BillDubuque Yeah, I had noticed the comment while I was typing out the solution and thought you might have had the same idea in mind

Thanks, I think I get it now !
